# Spring Boot: Can't find File located in resources folder with @Value annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Simple problem (I think): I'm attempting to load files with the `@Value` annotation, but Spring Boot does not see a file there.

```
@Value("classpath:/*.xlsx")
private Resource[] inputResources;
```

I'm using `inputResources` as an input to a Spring Batch method, which then fetches all files matching my wildcard.

```
MultiResourceItemReader<Employee> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<Employee>();
resourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
```

The Excel spreadsheets are located in my `resources` folder. Any reason why this wouldn't work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Value Annotation is used in Spring to read a single value from a property file. It can not be used to read a whole file.

To read a file try something like this:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:data.txt");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
...
```

You could use @Value to have this String "classpath:data.txt" not hardcoded.

Comment: I guess I misspoke. I'm following an example that sets file names as inputs to a method, which Spring later goes out to pull. I'm getting an error that there are no resources in that location. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Incorrect, You can actually use @Value to load resources link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-load-resource-as-string#using-spel